# Combining rows on a Dataframe based on a specific column value and add other values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe and I'm looking to combine two of the same column values together but leave all the others as they were.

For example:

```
c1            c2

shark         20
pizza         25
asteroid      10
shark         90
asteroid      30
```

And I want it to combine everything in the `c1` column with ONLY the value `shark` and add the values from `c2` so I get this:

```
c1            c2

shark         110
pizza         25
asteroid      10
asteroid      30
```

`groupby` combines everything which is not what I want.

I'm guessing using `df.loc` will get me somewhere but I'm not sure how to apply it back to the dataframe so it's changes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`Groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

Pick rows from df where `c1 == 'shark'`, groupby and sum `c2`. Then `append` the remaining rows where `c1 != 'shark'` to the earlier dataframe.

```
In [2009]: x = df[df.c1 == 'shark'].groupby('c1', as_index=False).sum()
In [2012]: res = x.append(df[df.c1 != 'shark'])

In [2013]: res
Out[2013]: 
         c1   c2
0     shark  110
1     pizza   25
2  asteroid   10
4  asteroid   30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a go

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1' : ['shark', 'pizza', 'asteroid', 'shark', 'asteroid'], 'c2': [20, 25, 10, 90, 30]})
pd.pivot_table(df,index='c1',aggfunc=np.sum)

           c2
c1           
asteroid   40
pizza      25
shark     110
```

Comment: This is not the expected output.